# How to install a ceiling fan, with no existing light in a room in a mobile home?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm trying to install a ceiling fan in a room with no existing light. The light switch goes to an outlet on the wall. I've been using a lamp for light. The walls are not drywall. And I have no attic access.

Can I direct mount a box to the ceiling on a stud, or do I have to cut a hole? Also for power am I able to run an extension cord or Romex to plug in the fan?

Comment: I would say it is highly difficult and impractical to install a ceiling fan without access to the framing above.

Comment: Extension cords are for temporary use only, run something for a short period of time.  Not to attach to walls/ceilings.  Ceilings fans need to be attached well to the ceiling so they don't fall on you.

Comment: Since it's a mobile home, can you post photos of the outlet box that's switched by the lightswitch?